# How do websites like Mangafox.com update its content so quick?

Tags: website-features

Was just curious as to how websites like mangafox update their content so quick. Do they have people watching different sites or do they usually have some automated program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick look at the site and their [FAQs](http://www.mangafox.com/faq/), it looks like MangaFox is an online manga archive where users can upload mangas to share with others. So "they" are not the only ones posting updates. I imagine most of the updates are posted by members.

Just looking at their forum, they have over 688,000 members. With a community that size, they really don't need to have an organized system for aggregating content. Most members are already "watching" the manga scene and scouring the internet for manga content, which they'll post to the site if relevant.

There are also dedicated groups that scan, subtitle, and distribute mangas online. Presumably, some of these people are members or have followers who are members of the site. So just by having access to the content by a few of these groups, and by different members responding to requests from other forum members, they're bound to have a fair amount of updates.

Though, a few updates every 2-3 hours isn't really that quick for a site of this size. Sites like [/.](http://slashdot.org) are updated at least once every half hour from user-contributed and staff-edited content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just a bit of an add-on, I know you can add dynamic elements such as a stock tickers which updates itself but I was wondering are there practices where people use automated programs to scan websites for updates to automatically add new content?

Comment: @moneyescapede: Yes, many sites/apps scrape other sites for content or data. The legality of it isn't always clear though, and the sites you scrape my ban the IP of your scrapers.